# Spring config: Nested env variable into SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON

Tags: spring, spring-config

Could I nest additional env variables into environment variable `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`?

Example:

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"spring": {"datasource": { "url":"$ENV_URL", "username":"$ENV_USER", "password":"$ENV_PASSWD" } } }'
```

Is it going to work right?

Comment: what do you mean? how to parse it?

Comment: Will nested `$ENV_URL` be resolved?